# Error: No such  file or directory

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to extract data from a XML file with python. I tried the following code.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
 tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("data_v2.xml")
```

Error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data_v2.xml'.
```

Comment: Your code assumes that `data_v2.xml` exists in the directory you are running the code from.  What happens if you use a full directory path?

Answer (score 9):

This is not XML error. This means that `data_v2.xml` does not exist -- system (operation system) cannot find it. Maybe this name is wrong, maybe you need to provide full path.

```
import traceback
# ...
try:
    input_fname = "data_v2.xml"
    tree.parse(input_fname)
    # ...
except IOError:
    ex_info = traceback.format_exc()
    print('ERROR!!! Cannot parse file: %s' % (input_fname))
    print('ERROR!!! Check if this file exists and you have right to read it!')
    print('ERROR!!! Exception info:\n%s' % (ex_info))
```

Comment: can you provide sample of try/exept to overcome this type of problem?

Comment: Of course. You must do it in `except IOError:` block of code